# Subdomain from different S3 bucket on same cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

- I have example.com served from idxxxx.cloudfront.net, this goes to S3 bucket nr 1. This works well.
- I now need subdomain.example.com to also be served from same cloudfront distribution, and point to S3 bucket nr 2. It's a completely different static website hosted on this bucket.

What I tried: 
I edited origins for my idxxxx.cloudfront.net distribution - I added a new origin there, to point to S3 bucket nr 2, then in Route53 I added this new recordset: 
Name: subdomain.example.com
Type: A - IPv4 Address 
Alias: yes
Alias target: idxxxx.cloudfront.net

The outcome of this attempt: calling subdomain.example.com shows me the contents of S3 bucket nr1 when my intention was to show the content of S3 bucket nr 2 on this subdomain. Is this because for my use case I actually must create another CF distribution? Or can I somehow work with the same distribution?

Maybe useful info -  my CF distribution is configured for these CNAMEs: example.com, *.example.com

I also tried adding in Route53 the IPv4 alias that points directly to the S3 bucket nr 2 for subdomain.example.com, and while it works to show me the desired contents of bucket 2, its not retrieved through cloudfront as I actually want it, therefore I dont benefit from things like https and such.

Is my use case impossible with just one CF distribution? Many thanks in advance.
Best regards,

Comment: I'm posting the answer for the question you've asked... but in case I am missing something, I'll also ask: what is your motivation for using 1 (free) distribution instead of 2 (free) distributions?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot because of the cost for having two separate CF distributions :) I thought I could try to use one distribution for both. Please tell me what do you mean by (free) distributions? As I understood, each CF distribution is billed separately.

Comment: There isn't a charge for a CloudFront distribution -- an actual CloudFront distribution itself has no associated cost.  You pay a charge per request handled by CloudFront, and a charge per gigabyte of traffic. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: Yes but the ACLs are a cost per cloudfront, so multiple cloudfronts are a multiplier effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's a completely different static website

A completely different web site needs a completely separate CloudFront distribution.  Identical sites with multiple domain names would be the case where you'd serve multiple sites and associate multiple hostnames from a single distribution.